# SOAP and file_get_contents() fails to retrieve wsdl from nonstandard port

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to get some prices from a web service at:

http://icelit02.elit.cz:7606/InterCompany-1.10.0/BuyerService?wsdl

with code:

```
$wsdl = 'http://icelit02.elit.cz:7606/InterCompany-1.10.0/BuyerService?wsdl';
$opts = array('http' => array('protocol_version' => '1.0'));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('stream_context' => $context));


var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); 
var_dump($client->__getTypes());
```

and it fails with:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://icelit02.elit.cz:7606/InterCompany-1.10.0/BuyerService?wsdl' : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home/cererepi/public_html/elit/connect.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /home/cererepi/public_html/elit/connect.php(6): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://icelit02...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/cererepi/public_html/elit/connect.php on line 6
```

I tried to get the xml at that address with

```
$xmlfile = file_get_contents ( 'http://icelit02.elit.cz:7606/InterCompany-1.10.0/BuyerService?wsdl' );
```

Again, failed with no error but an empty string.

Comment: Copying your code exactly works correctly for me.  Do you have `error_reporting()` on `E_ALL`? `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` I wonder if your setting for `allow_url_fopen` is turned off.

Comment: No, allow_url_fopen is on, and file_get_contents returns no error.

Comment: Check `print_r($http_response_header)` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Comment: Copied the entire block from the link you provided, the response: NULL NULL. You can check this now at this address: http://cererepieseauto.ro/elit/connect.php

Comment: The slow load does suggest a network or firewall issue. You didn't specify - are you able to retrieve that XML just from your browser? Via the command line with `wget` or `curl -G`?

Comment: I don't have another access to hosting machine :( than FTP.
Of course, in my browser the xml loads fine, but I'm not at the server.

Comment: Can you get _other_ URL's via `file_get_contents()`, or does only this one fail? (suggesting that the target site is explicitly blocking it)

Comment: I've tried another URL (www.prosport.ro) that worked, but it was served on port 80.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. I didn't even notice the `7606`. Check with your host's support. They may explicitly be blocking outbound ports other than 80/443 and some common ones for shared hosting clients.

Comment: OK, I'll check with them after holydays. It's there any method to check this by myself?

Comment: It would be difficult to test with only FTP access. You would need to write a script that attempts to open a socket on that port but I don't think you would be able to learn much. To truly test would require shell access.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working well i think you have enabled some security features like the `allow_url_fopen`. Set that value in your **php.ini** to `on`.

Its no SSL otherwise you have to check the openssl extension, too.

Comment: ini_get('allow_url_fopen') returns true

Comment: Do you have some output before? I have copied your code and it work working. Perhaps copy that part to a new file and test it again.

Comment: No, there is only one two lines of code: 1: $xmlfile = file_get_contents (..., 2: var_dump ( $xmlfile ).
I suspect there's something wrong with apache config, or firewall or...